# Using threeGLTFLoader load gltf get transparency problem

Tags: three.js, gltf

I try to use threeGLTFLoader to load gltf ,problem with the material,the model is a man’s head but now i could see the back
here is the code:

```
var threeGLTFLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

var objPositions;

threeGLTFLoader.load("../resources/untitled.gltf", function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;
    model.name = "man";
    model.scale.set(300, 300, 300);
    root.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    root.updateMatrix();
    root.add(model);
});
```

[image]

[image]

The link of [3D model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/kolya-477d20161e224255abc6275f784a8056)

Comment: Are you using `GLTFLoader` from the official `three` npm package or from a third-party package?

Comment: just download from the official   [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js)

Comment: Are there two models here? The 2nd image looks different, and looks totally fine in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ (which also uses three.js)... can you share the complete code for your scene? Including the camera creation especially. Might need a higher near plane or a smaller far plane on the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Without the model it's hard to guess what's going on here, but I'll wager a guess based on seeing this kind of back-is-in-front rendering before.

I think your glTF model probably has materials that are marked `"alphaMode": "BLEND"`.

In most realtime 3D rendering systems, including ThreeJS, blended or translucent materials will disable the depth buffer, and can be rendered out of order.  There are ways for some engines to fix or work around this, but they can cost performance and increase complexity.

For opaque materials in a glTF file, the best thing to do is leave `alphaMode` set to its default value `OPAQUE`.  Only materials that really need to be translucent should be set to `BLEND`.

Comment: Thank you for you help !   I also tried this [model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/kolya-477d20161e224255abc6275f784a8056)  get same problem ,the model has no transparency materials.   How to set alphaMode ,using a 3D software like Blender or inside Three.js

Answer (score 0):

Ed Mackey’s answer on GitHub is a good explanation of why this is happening. If you’re the author of the model, it’s an issue you could fix by disabling transparency on parts of the model that aren’t meant to be transparent. If you’re not the author of the model, you can override the incorrect transparency settings after loading the model in three.js:

```js
model.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) object.material.transparent = false;
});
```

This code will disable transparency everywhere on the model. In more complex cases you may need to select specific parts of the mesh to override, and that is easier to do in Blender, using Alpha Clip or Opaque modes.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tested  with your code like this
 
```js
var threeGLTFLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
var objPositions;
threeGLTFLoader.load("../resources/untitled.gltf", function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;
    model.name = "man";
    model.scale.set(300, 300, 300);
    model.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) object.material.transparent = false;
});
    root.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    root.updateMatrix();
    root.add(model);
});

``` 
but not working still same problem 
The model has no transparency parts  it's show right in blender

Comment: The 2nd model has a different problem. You may find it easier to ask this question on https://discourse.threejs.org/, it is easier to reply back and forth in forums.

Comment: OK Thank you  I am go back to discourse.threejs.org